# How to call a non-member function that takes in an object within a method

Tags: c++, member, non-member-functions

Say I have a class Student, and I have already declared a non-member function called "function_A" that takes in as an argument, type Student.

Now say INSIDE the Student class, I had a member function, and in it, I wanted to reference the non-member function, "function_A", declared earlier. What would I pass in as the argument (the argument itself must be type Student).

[code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5826452/how-come-my-code-does-not-work)

Comment: This type of question works best with some sample code to illustrate the problem.

Answer (score 3):

Do you mean something like this?

```
void function_A(Student s);

class Student { 
   void function_A() {
        ::function_A(*this);
   }
```

if the member function's name is different than `function_A`, I can't see any problem.

Comment: ah, is the "*this" just a reference to the object we're dealing with?

Comment: hmm... actually i'm still getting an error saying "variable or field 'function_A()' declared void"

Comment: seems like its a problem with the Student s argument that's being passed in... hmm

Comment: @Simone: In this case, you do not pass by reference, but by value. A copy of the student will be created.

Comment: @Simone @Space_C0wb0y Yeah that's true. But even without the &, the program should at least run. Right now, i am getting the error mentioned above (with or without &).

Comment: @google: Then you should post your actual code (edit it into your question) so that we can help you. If the code is long, try to construct a minimal working example that reproduces the error, and post that.

Comment: @Space_C0wb0y Okay I will do that.

Comment: Please see code here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5826452/how-come-my-code-does-not-work