# Trying to define a function, but I get "variable or field `function_A' declared void"

Tags: c++

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Student;
void function_A(Student& s)

class Student { 
   void function_B() {
        ::function_A(*this);
   }
   int courses;
};

void function_A(Student& s)
{ // line 18 (where error is occurring)
     s.courses = 1;
}

int main()
{
    Student s;
    s.function_B();
    return 0;
}
```

The error that I am getting is as follows:

> (line 18) New types may not be defined in a return type.

Comment: +1.  This is trickier than it looks.  I edited the title to make it more descriptive.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow!  Great question, but please don't change your code while people are still answering your question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Part of your problem is you're using the type `Student` before it's defined by making it a parameter to `function_A`.  To make this work you need to

1. Add a forward declaration `function_A`
2. Switch `function_A` to take a pointer or reference
3. Move `function_A` after `Student`.  This is necessary so member `courses` is defined before it's accessed
4. Add a `;` after the end of the `class Student` definition

Try the following

```
class Student;
void function_A(Student& s);

class Student { 
   // All of the student code
};

void function_A(Student& s) {
  s.courses = 1;
}
```

Comment: On top of that, an `;` is needed after the class definition.

Comment: @AndreyT didn't notice that.  Updated the answer.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You have to forward declare `Student`.

Place

```
 class Student;
```

before `function_A`.

Comment: A forward declaration isn't sufficient either, since the Student object is being passed by value, and function_A references a member variable of the Student class.